# Can i pass more than one value at single button's value in PHP?

Tags: php

I tried with the following code but it is not working.Please anyone help me with this.Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<button class="delete btn btn-warning" value= $row['id'] " " $row['vehicle'] ><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</button>
```

Comment: first concat value and store in one variable. than pas it.

Comment: `value= '<?php echo $row['id']. " " .$row['vehicle']; ?>'`

Comment: Can you post more code to understand the question much better

Comment: Thank you so much @urfusion it works for me and i am new to php and making silly mistakes like this

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for string concatenation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
<button class="delete btn btn-warning" value="<?= $row['id'] . " " . 
$row['vehicle'] ?>"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="delete btn btn-warning" value='<?php $row['id'] ?>" "<?php $row['vehicle'] ?>'><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</button>
```

if your `$row` fields are set correctly then this code will work for you

Comment: You can't give a space separated value without quotes

Comment: Ah you were faster than my edit i just saw it also :) edited my answer

Comment: looks perfect now...

Answer (score 0):

on of possible way is, use json for parsing data here

```
<input value="<?php echo json_encode($row); ?>" />
```

then decode it again by `json_decode()`